# Webform results table not displaying

Tags: webform-civicrm

I have numerous webforms set up.  When I click on 'results' then 'table' there seems to be an issue with viewing any of the results there.  The results are there, as in, they can be downloaded and viewed individually through 'submissions'.  All I  can see are the titles of each column.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the Results and Table aspects you refer to are purely Drupal components. We have built many hundreds of webform_civicrm forms and have never seen a problem with this so I doubt the problem is specifically an issue due to using civicrm.

You could try right-clicking and using your browsers 'inspector' to check the console and see if it shows any errors.

Otherwise try searching/asking in either the Drupal stackexchange or in the Drupal project Issues pages - and hopefully they won't say 'this is a civi issue' (unless of course it is and I am wrong)

Comment: I've never seen any issues with Results either...